Ros2 controller not loading with the following error. [controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'manipulator_moveit_controller'
I am using ROS Iron, and have used the moveit setup assistant for my URDF package. I have 2 different controllers and when I try to launch the demo.launch.py this is the output I get. NOTE: I can plan the path but can't execute.
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/deep2d/.ros/log/2024-08-01-14-57-39-877416-deep2d-System-Product-Name-17555
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-1]: process started with pid [17558]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [17560]
[INFO] [move_group-3]: process started with pid [17562]
[INFO] [rviz2-4]: process started with pid [17564]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-5]: process started with pid [17566]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [17568]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [17570]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [17572]
[static_transform_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722538660.803128722] [static_transform_publisher0]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-1] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-1] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-1] from 'fixed_frame' to 'base_footprint'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.835445938] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '/robot_description' topic for robot description.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.835556074] [controller_manager]: update rate is 100 Hz
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.835763575] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1722538660.839867551] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1722538660.840041744] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1722538660.840058917] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1722538660.840069770] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_2
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1722538660.840080023] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_3
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1722538660.840089526] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_4
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1722538660.840098949] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_5
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1722538660.840108913] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_6
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1722538660.840118543] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_arm_fixed_base
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1722538660.840128246] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_z_axis
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.840338203] [controller_manager]: Received robot description from topic.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.840494816] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'FakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.841103049] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'FakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1722538660.841140532] [mock_generic_system]: Parsing of optional initial interface values failed or uses a deprecated format. Add initial values for every state interface in the ros2_control.xacro. For example: 
[ros2_control_node-5] <state_interface name="velocity"> 
[ros2_control_node-5]   <param name="initial_value">0.0</param> 
[ros2_control_node-5] </state_interface>
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.841152169] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.841198336] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'FakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.841202853] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.841208054] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'FakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538660.841210964] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'FakeSystem'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.869655249] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00377823 seconds
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.869789024] [move_group.moveit.moveit.core.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'custom_mycobot'...
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1722538660.869835607] [move_group.moveit.moveit.core.robot_model]: Link base_footprint has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.890196041] [move_group.moveit.moveit.kinematics.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'gantry': 1
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.890471004] [move_group.moveit.moveit.kinematics.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'manipulator': 1 1 1 1 1 1
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.934434800] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.934570867] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.moveit_cpp]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.935329760] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.935727022] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.935743246] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopping existing planning scene publisher.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.935834419] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopped publishing maintained planning scene.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.936087387] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.936151940] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.936416708] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.936433525] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.937032646] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.937317221] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1722538660.938014696] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-3] [ERROR] [1722538660.938032403] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.946614988] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.952184319] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.command_planner]: Available plugins: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP 
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.952218441] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.command_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.953808210] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.command_planner]: Registered Algorithm [CIRC]
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.953835771] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.command_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.955545330] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.command_planner]: Registered Algorithm [LIN]
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.955572590] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.command_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.956535877] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.command_planner]: Registered Algorithm [PTP]
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.956569261] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_pipeline]: Successfully loaded planner 'Pilz Industrial Motion Planner'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.958946157] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/ResolveConstraintFrames'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.959865687] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/ResolveConstraintFrames'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.959883124] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/ValidateWorkspaceBounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.960055428] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/ValidateWorkspaceBounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.960063234] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/CheckStartStateBounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.960081091] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/CheckStartStateBounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.960085334] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/CheckStartStateCollision'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.960101698] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/CheckStartStateCollision'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.962493439] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/ValidateSolution'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538660.968196325] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.002065652] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/CheckStartStateCollision'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.002075961] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/CheckStartStateCollision'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.004279678] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/AddTimeOptimalParameterization'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.004759490] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/AddTimeOptimalParameterization'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.004775533] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/ValidateSolution'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.005164551] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/ValidateSolution'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.005180472] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/DisplayMotionPath'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.005485727] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/DisplayMotionPath'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.009938689] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_pipeline]: Successfully loaded planner 'STOMP'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.012374624] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/ResolveConstraintFrames'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.012583061] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/ResolveConstraintFrames'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.012591400] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/ValidateWorkspaceBounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.012780424] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/ValidateWorkspaceBounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.012793125] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/CheckStartStateBounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.012816886] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/CheckStartStateBounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.012821375] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/CheckStartStateCollision'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.012836530] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_request_adapters/CheckStartStateCollision'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.015037060] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/AddTimeOptimalParameterization'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.015507431] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/AddTimeOptimalParameterization'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.015521727] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/ValidateSolution'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.015930609] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/ValidateSolution'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.015947411] [move_group]: Try loading adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/DisplayMotionPath'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.016252166] [move_group]: Loaded adapter 'default_planning_response_adapters/DisplayMotionPath'
[move_group-3] [ERROR] [1722538661.047858359] [move_group.moveit.moveit.plugins.simple_controller_manager]: Unknown controller type: follow_joint_trajectory/FollowJointTrajectory
[move_group-3] [ERROR] [1722538661.047913149] [move_group.moveit.moveit.plugins.simple_controller_manager]: Unknown controller type: follow_joint_trajectory/FollowJointTrajectory
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.048026869] [move_group.moveit.moveit.plugins.simple_controller_manager]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.048042704] [move_group.moveit.moveit.plugins.simple_controller_manager]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.048575008] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.048607593] [move_group]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
[move_group-3] [ERROR] [1722538661.110849915] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.executable]: Exception while loading move_group capability 'moveit_config.move_group_capabilities': According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class moveit_config.move_group_capabilities with base class type move_group::MoveGroupCapability does not exist. Declared types are  move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService move_group/ClearOctomapService move_group/ExecuteTaskSolutionCapability move_group/GetUrdfService move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService move_group/MoveGroupExecuteService move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction move_group/MoveGroupPlanService move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService move_group/TfPublisher pilz_industrial_motion_planner/MoveGroupSequenceAction pilz_industrial_motion_planner/MoveGroupSequenceService
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.112772839] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.move_group_sequence_action]: initialize move group sequence action
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.115006462] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.115223322] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.115885291] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.executable]: 
[move_group-3] 
[move_group-3] ********************************************************
[move_group-3] * MoveGroup using: 
[move_group-3] *     - apply_planning_scene_service
[move_group-3] *     - clear_octomap_service
[move_group-3] *     - get_group_urdf
[move_group-3] *     - CartesianPathService
[move_group-3] *     - execute_trajectory_action
[move_group-3] *     - get_planning_scene_service
[move_group-3] *     - kinematics_service
[move_group-3] *     - move_action
[move_group-3] *     - motion_plan_service
[move_group-3] *     - query_planners_service
[move_group-3] *     - state_validation_service
[move_group-3] *     - SequenceAction
[move_group-3] *     - SequenceService
[move_group-3] ********************************************************
[move_group-3] 
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.115932899] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.context]: MoveGroup context using pipeline ompl
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1722538661.115944756] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.context]: MoveGroup context initialization complete
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/GetUrdfService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'moveit_config.move_group_capabilities'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner/MoveGroupSequenceAction'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner/MoveGroupSequenceService'...
[move_group-3] 
[move_group-3] You can start planning now!
[move_group-3] 
[ros2_control_node-5] [ERROR] [1722538661.139942870] [controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'gantry_moveit_controller'.
[spawner-6] [FATAL] [1722538661.151075944] [spawner_gantry_moveit_controller]: Failed loading controller gantry_moveit_controller
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538661.156374898] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538661.157139497] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5)
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538661.221563062] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 17568, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/iron/lib/controller_manager/spawner gantry_moveit_controller --ros-args'].
[rviz2-4] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-4]          at line 321 in /opt/ros/iron/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538661.342591621] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [ERROR] [1722538661.376884079] [controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'manipulator_moveit_controller'.
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1722538661.378023253] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[spawner-7] [FATAL] [1722538661.378502480] [spawner_manipulator_moveit_controller]: Failed loading controller manipulator_moveit_controller
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538661.379998554] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1722538661.380157439] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1722538661.417450632] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 17570, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/iron/lib/controller_manager/spawner manipulator_moveit_controller --ros-args'].
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process has finished cleanly [pid 17572]
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1722538664.359866355] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.385855212] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.561036161] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.ros.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.0593852 seconds
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.561116036] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.core.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'custom_mycobot'...
[rviz2-4] [WARN] [1722538664.561205536] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.core.robot_model]: Link base_footprint has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.583580887] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.kinematics.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'gantry': 1
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.584011395] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.kinematics.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'manipulator': 1 1 1 1 1 1
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.634907913] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.635587374] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.660692708] [interactive_marker_display_94082960670560]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.670662808] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: group gantry
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.670693384] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'gantry' in namespace ''
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.682792102] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.ros.move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group gantry.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.684472970] [moveit_2179598651.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: group gantry
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.703514312] [interactive_marker_display_94082960670560]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1722538664.744916541] [interactive_marker_display_94082960670560]: Service response received for initialization
[ros2_control_node-5] [ERROR] [1722539160.990283212] [controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'gantry_moveit_controller'.
[ros2_control_node-5] [ERROR] [1722539186.648671354] [controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'gantry_moveit_controller'.

This is my XACRO control file for reference
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <ros2_control name="${name}" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <!-- By default, set up controllers for simulation. This won't work on real hardware -->
            <plugin>mock_components/GenericSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>
        <joint name="joint_z_axis">
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['joint_z_axis']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="joint_1">
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['joint_1']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="joint_2">
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['joint_2']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="joint_3">
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['joint_3']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="joint_4">
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['joint_4']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="joint_5">
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['joint_5']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="joint_6">
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['joint_6']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>

    </ros2_control>
</xacro:macro>

ros2_controller.yaml
# This config file is used by ros2_control

controller_manager:
ros__parameters:
update_rate: 100  # Hz
gantry_controller:
  type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController


manipulator_controller:
  type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController


joint_state_broadcaster:
  type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

gantry_controller:
ros__parameters:
joints:
- joint_z_axis
command_interfaces:
- position
state_interfaces:
- position
- velocity
allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end: true
manipulator_controller:
ros__parameters:
joints:
- joint_1
- joint_2
- joint_3
- joint_4
- joint_5
- joint_6
command_interfaces:
- position
state_interfaces:
- position
- velocity
allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end: true
moveit_controller.yaml
# MoveIt uses this configuration for controller management

moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager
moveit_simple_controller_manager:
controller_names:
- gantry_moveit_controller
- manipulator_moveit_controller
gantry_moveit_controller:
type: follow_joint_trajectory/FollowJointTrajectory
action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
default: true
joints:
- joint_z_axis
action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
default: true
manipulator_moveit_controller:
type: follow_joint_trajectory/FollowJointTrajectory
action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
default: true
joints:
- joint_1
- joint_2
- joint_3
- joint_4
- joint_5
- joint_6
action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
default: true
I have tried changing the type format, manually trying to load the controller from CLI, pass the type as arguments to the node.
